# Does wayland support video card(s) resource isolation?

Tags: vnc, docker, amd-v

From what I know, with hypervisors, I need an IOMMU capable motherboard and multiple graphics cards to run multiple virtualized instances remotely (correct me if I'm wrong). ESXi allows for virtualized instances in such a manner, where a user gets graphics card support as opposed to just a terminal.

Is that the case with wayland? What about multiple vnc sessions? Are multiple vnc sessions supported by a single Linux OS like CentOS 6? What about dockers and wayland? Would dockers isolate resources on the graphics card and wayland or x server not really matter?

Business goal: whether or not wayland is made for graphics containerization, like is the case for cpu, ram, etc. for docker.

Comment: Maybe this question would fit better on Stack Overflow? It seems like a question more for programmers to answer than sysadmins; also there are [wayland] and [iommu] tags there. I can flag it to be moved if you like.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is on topic here as written to begin with (and [the community appears to agree](http://serverfault.com/review/reopen/135940)). I think it would be better if you described exactly what your business requirements are and the problem you are trying to solve. If this isn't for professional system administration, you may find an answer to this particular question on [unix.se].

Comment: I disagree as to whether the topic is not on topic.  I reworded the question - there's no stupid questions and this is a sys admin related and not unix.stackexchange.com related because I want to know what wayland is capable of for ESXi, docker users - sys. admins.

Comment: Beware, though, @paulcube, that just because the question is on topic doesn't mean there are people who can give you a good answer, thus another reason why the question may be better suited for a different site.

Comment: You really still should describe your business requirements and overall problem. Questions like this are a strong indication that you may be [chasing a wild goose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: Fair point, updated the question in regards to the business information I'm looking for.